# Gift taxes if I let my sister live rent free in a house I own?

Tags: united-states, first-time-home-buyer, gift-tax

If I buy a home for my special needs sister to live in free of charge, is this a gift for taxation purposes since $0 is under fair market value?

I assume if it is considered a gift, since the amount given to her is just on the value as if it was a rental and not on: taxes, interest, and repairs. Is that right?

- In the US.
- I won't live there.
- I don't own a home of my own.
- She will not be on the deed.
- I will pay all of the taxes.
- She is not considered my dependent.

Comment: Why did you ask the same question twice? https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/88593/what-are-my-options-for-tax-deductions-if-buying-a-house-for-my-sister-complica

Comment: Sorry, I legitimately considered it two questions. One about deductions I could take, and another about taxes I could owe.

Comment: Are you married? Is your sister married? Will she pay for repairs/maintenance, or anything else that might not typically be paid for by tenant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(What you're doing is very nice.)

https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed/frequently-asked-questions-on-gift-taxes#5

> For 2018, the annual exclusion is $15,000.

If the fair market value of **rent** (since renters don't pay property taxes, repair costs, etc... just rent) is less than `$15000/12 = $1250/month` then it falls under the annual exclusion.  If FMV rent is over $1250/month, you'll have to -- I think -- file form 709 https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i709.pdf and pay taxes on anything over $15K (or deduct it from your -- as of 2017 -- $5MM lifetime estate exclusion).

(EDIT: remember that you can't deduct mortgage interest since it's not your primary dwelling.)

(EDIT 2: I'd strongly recommend you look at how to turn the rent gift into a charitable donation.  It might not be possible, but certainly worth a look.)

Comment: I'm curious to know how this would be regulated. If his sister just lives there and pays nothing and the OP declares nothing, then how would the irs know otherwise? I'm not saying its a good idea/legal, just curious.

Comment: @stanri how would the IRS know whether my father just wrote me a check for $50K?  They wouldn't, until/unless they audited him.  Thus, the IRS relies on honesty.

Comment: Why the down-vote?

Comment: the IRS does know about a check for $50k (in fact, every transaction, regardless of value) is tracked. That is the beauty of this situation. There is no transaction to track. Sister lives in house; no money changes hand, no contracts. No paper trail.

Comment: @rocketman "*the IRS does know about a check for $50k*" Citation?

Comment: You [cannot deduct donations to an individual](https://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc506), only a qualified organization which except for churches and governments must have obtained a 501(c)(3) determination from the IRS -- and only if you itemize, which many people will no longer benefit from under the just-passed reform.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I figured as much, but didn't know for sure.

Comment: The IRS will know about a check for $50,000 as long as it is processed through an American bank, as there are forms that banks/financial institutions have to file for transactions greater than $10000