# Do I have to pay gift tax on gifts in kind?

Tags: united-states, gift-tax

Let's say I am letting out a room in my house on AirBnB for $100 per night. Then one day a relative of mine is down on his luck, so I take it off the market and instead let him stay in that room. I don't charge him anything. There is no formal agreement. The arrangement last for many months.

Is my gift of sleeping accommodation liable for gift tax? How is the value of it assessed?

How about if I let him use my car?

A key thing here is that what I am "giving" him cannot be resold. If I give him a house or a car he could then resell that, but if I let him stay in my house he can't sell that to someone else.

Is it different if he is not a relative? How is it different if he is my spouse?

References please.

Comment: Gifts under $15,000 annually are free, and even gifts over $15K "just" need to be deducted from the inheritance exclusion.  No references, so no answer.

Comment: I'm aware of the exclusions, that's not what I'm interested in. And assume that there is no likelihood of inheritance.

Comment: Why aren't you interested?  After all, you're **giving** your relative the gift of staying there rent free. Ergo, the gift exclusion seems relevant.

Comment: Because I'm interested in the principle, not the details. What if the "market value" of my gift was more than $15,000?

Comment: The principle is that the first $15,000 is excluded.

Comment: If you don't want to answer the question, feel free to not answer it.

Comment: Gifts to spouses are never subject to gift tax.

Comment: This may actually be a dup (and it's kind of funny considering who answered it, possibly better there than here): https://money.stackexchange.com/q/88594/17718

Comment: @TTT looks duplicate to me... :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gift taxes if I let my sister live rent free in a house I own?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/88594/gift-taxes-if-i-let-my-sister-live-rent-free-in-a-house-i-own)

Comment: It kinda does, but it doesn't make a reference for the point I am asking. It just assumes that the rent-free living will count as a gift. Pretty close though.

Comment: @RonJohn I don't think the answer to the other question is right. Without a transfer of money/property, I don't see how this situation triggers gift/estate tax considerations. It might change the status of the property from business to personal use, but that's an unrelated tax issue.

Answer (score 1):

[This article](https://bizfluent.com/info-8617156-irs-rent-property-management-services.html) indicates that providing a below-market rent would, at most, convert the property from business use, which would allow for certain deductions/depreciation, to personal use, which would not.

I am not a lawyer/tax professional, but my sense from reading the [IRS Gift Tax FAQs](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed/frequently-asked-questions-on-gift-taxes) is that there is an assumption that gifts are money, property, or other tangible things of value. The whole point of the gift tax infrastructure seems to be to reduce estate tax avoidance. If you're not giving someone something they can spend or sell or get an income from (as in an interest in a business), I don't think it's a gift for these purposes; it's just a personal favor.

Comment: That's a good link, but to my reading the FAQ would indicate that in-kind is a gift: "What is considered a gift? Any transfer to an individual, either directly or indirectly, where full consideration (measured in money or money's worth) is not received in return."

Comment: @DJClayworth I think the keyword there is "transfer". The thing you're gifting has to have a value that the recipient can transfer to yet another person or entity. If I were an electrician, but did a little home rewiring for friend/relative, where they paid for the materials, I don't think the value of my time is considered a gift. If *I* paid for the materials and didn't get reimbursement, the value of the materials *would* be a gift (though not likely big enough to require paperwork, unless the wires were made of gold).